# Syncfusion Grid Grouping Control Extend

Tags: syncfusion

I am trying to create a custom control by extending the GridGroupingControl. The grid is working fine in the page without the columns descriptors. To add the column descriptors i have extended the GrdiColumnDescriptor class and created my own control which i am trying to add in the aspx.

The code is as follows

*****Grid*****

```
 public class CustomGrid : GridGroupingControl
    {
         public CustomGrid(): base() <br>
         {
         }
    }
```

***GridColumn***

```
public class CustomGridColumnDescriptor : GridColumnDescriptor
{
public CustomGridColumnDescriptor ()
            : base()
        {
        }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<Custom:CustomGrid ....>
<TalbleDescriptor>
<Columns>
<Custom:CustomGridColumnDescriptor ....>
<Custom:CustomGridColumnDescriptor ....>
<Custom:CustomGridColumnDescriptor ....>
....
```

But while implementing i get this following error
"The type ASIGridColumnDescriptor was not expected. Use the
XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known
statically."
Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 1):

To use the extended column descriptor, you need to extend both `ColumnsCollection` and `TableDescriptor` and use those like these.

```
<CustomTableDescriptor>
<CustomColumn>
<Custom:CustomGridColumnDescriptor ....>
<Custom:CustomGridColumnDescriptor ....>
<Custom:CustomGridColumnDescriptor ....>
```